# Docker hangs while building image when running a long command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have a simple docker file which installs a compiler (IAR EWARM) in a Windows image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

WORKDIR /docker_work

# Copy the IAR installation media and do the install
COPY ./Environment/EWARM_8302_18209_install_media /EWARM_8302_18209_install_media
COPY ./Environment/IAR_install_iss /IAR_install_iss
RUN C:\EWARM_8302_18209_install_media\ew\setup.exe /s \
    /f1"C:\IAR_install_iss\setup.iss"                 \
    /f2"C:\docker_work\iar_install.log"

COPY ./IAR ./IAR
```

I expect this installation to take approximately 10 minutes to complete on my system. However I've noticed it doesn't seem to run to completion on its own. I can walk away from the system and come back and it looks like that step is still in process. If I enter a key I get output that says the step is complete.

Example Output:

```
PS C:\work\my_project> docker build -t iar_env . ; docker run -it --rm iar_env powershell.exe
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.246GB
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903
 ---> ab37d72f0d0e
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /docker_work
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2bc1fcd7970
Step 3/6 : COPY ./Environment/EWARM_8302_18209_install_media /EWARM_8302_18209_install_media
 ---> 743e35532adf
Step 4/6 : COPY ./Environment/IAR_install_iss /IAR_install_iss
 ---> 230c9d3afa0c
Step 5/6 : RUN C:\EWARM_8302_18209_install_media\ew\setup.exe /s     /f1"C:\IAR_install_iss\setup.iss"                     /f2"C:\docker_work\iar_install.log"
 ---> Running in c0caf75330f0 <------- The hang occurs here. If I hit the enter key the build continues
Removing intermediate container c0caf75330f0
 ---> 061050e6b765
Step 6/6 : COPY ./IAR ./IAR
 ---> ef1d0e9d34dd
Successfully built ef1d0e9d34dd
Successfully tagged iar_env:latest
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\docker_work> ls


    Directory: C:\docker_work


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/20/2020  11:47 AM                IAR
-a----        5/20/2020  11:40 AM            186 iar_install.log


PS C:\docker_work> cat .\iar_install.log
[InstallShield Silent]
Version=v7.00
File=Log File
[ResponseResult]
ResultCode=0
[Application]
Name=IAR Embedded Workbench for Arm
Version=8.30.2
Company=IAR Systems
Lang=0409
PS C:\docker_work>
```

I am running Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b. This problem only happens when step five actually needs to be run and cache cannot be used. This may not be a day to day problem, but I am concerned it will cause my build server to hang if for some reason it needs to rebuild the image from scratch. Why might this hang be occurring?

Comment: I am no longer able to reproduce this issue. Several other people have independently tried running this dockerfile and have not encountered the issue.